Can i connect two DC-DC buck converters 48V>24V in parallel to increase the current?
can i connect two DC-DC buck converters 48V>24V in parallel to increase the output current?
I have one 20A already but it shuts off by overload. The Load is sometimes 30A so im considering to connect two of those in parallel. (The load is DC motor)
Is it bad idea?
Thanks


Are the converters specifically designed to be paralleled? If not, no.

Definitely not recommended. But one trick is to put low value resistors in series with each power supply to balance and decouple the convertors. You will lose a little efficiency and some voltage drop. A better idea is to get a convertor that is suitable for the load.
